# ActionScript and Arduino

Tags: flash, actionscript, arduino

I am making a game in Flash that uses the Arduino with two [passive infrared sensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor) (PIRs) attached. The idea is that these sensors will make an object on the stage in Flash move and follow your interaction. There are plenty of sites with information on the Arduino side of things, but it's the ActionScript side that is causing the problem. I have used ActionScript 3 glue and have connected Arduino to Flash before lighting LEDs that are powered by an button event listener in Flash, but nothing like this and unfortunately for me there is nothing online.

I can obtain a range of analogue values in the Arduino side of things showing how far an object is away from the sensor. How do I display an object so that when your hand is between 10 and 11 cm away from the distance sensor, the object will display at an x,y coordinate on the screen?

Comment: I don't understand... Are you successfully reading sensors' values in flash?

Comment: @Sr.Richie I can successfully read values when I run the Arduino code itself (opens an applet with values ranging upon distance from sensor) but nothing in flash. I am not sure where to even start with it.. The arduino code that I used is in the Arduino example 6 - sensors ping

Comment: Are you using as3 glue? have you followed the as3glue instructions? 
http://code.google.com/p/as3glue/wiki/Instructions

Comment: Yes I am using AS3 glue but the main problem I am having is actually reading the values from the Arduino and converting the values to x and y coordinates

Comment: So, is your serial-proxy working? Can you "trace" the values of the Arduino inside Flash or not? To help you we need you to be as specific as possible....